at least $n^2$ different integers of the form $x+yz$ where $x,y,z \in S$
let $S$ be a set of $n$ distinct positive integers. Prove that there are at least $n^2$ different integers of the form $x+yz$ where $x,y,z \in S$.(repetitiveness allowed for x,y,z)
All the possible combinations of x,y,z are $n^3$. If I assume there're less than $n^2$ different integers then according to the pigeonhole principle, there are at least an integer $N=x+yz$ can be achieved by more than n different (x,y,z). This is what I've thought about so far.

Working examples is always a good idea.  Letting $a_n$ be the number of  worst case values, what is the sequence ${a_n}$ for small $n$?

FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS thread at least n^2 integers written in the form x+yz with x,y,z\in S with basically the same problem, with it also stating that the source is the Mediterranean Mathematical Olympiad $2020$ P$2$ MMC.

@JohnOmielan Thanks for the link. I didn't find this on the internet before.

Hint
You can prove this by induction on $n$. Let $m$ be the largest number in $S$, and let $S'=S-\{m\}$. By the inductive hypothesis, you know that there are at least $(n-1)^2$ numbers of the form $xy+z$ using only $x,y,z\in S'$. Therefore, you just need to show there are at least $2n-1$ numbers of the form $xy+z$ where at least one of $x,y$ or $z$ is equal to $m$. Once you prove that, you get there are $(n-1)^2+2n-1=n^2$ numbers in total.
Think about how to select some particular numbers of the form $xy+z$, involving the largest number $m$, which are provably bigger than everything generated using $S'$ alone. You will need to take care to prove that your list of $2n-1$ numbers are pairwise distinct.
Solution

 Consider these two groups of numbers of the form $xy+z$:

     1. The $n$ numbers of the form $x\cdot m + m$, for some $x\in S$.
     2. The $n-1$ numbers of the form $m^2 + z$, for some $z\in S'$ (so $z\neq m$).

 These two groups are disjoint. Everything in the first group is a multiple of $m$, while everything in the second group is a non-multiple of $m$. This shows there are $2n-1$ numbers of the form $xy+z$ where at least one of $x,y,z$ is equal to $m$, completing the proof by induction.


This is a good answer. FYI, the solution to basically the same problem in the AoPS thread at least n^2 integers written in the form x+yz with x,y,z\in S is similar to yours, although I consider it to be a bit simpler.
